# Silverlight developer wants to gain some designer chops - where do I start?

Tags: silverlight, user-interface, xaml

I'd like to reskin a Silverlight app to be more visually compelling.  Unfortunately, I went to school for computer science, not design, and I have trouble deciding if two colors even match.  How do I get started?  Let me add that time and money are both factors so pursuing a design degree isn't an option (though it might be ideal).

EDIT: I also need to learn how to implement good design, so any guidance on the toolsets (Blend or Illustrator?) would be helpful too.

Comment: Design is about much much much more than colour schemes.

Comment: @devinb: True but I think James is using it simply as an example of the level of his need.

Comment: It's a common misconception I've noticed. I totally agree that he doesn't think that, but it's something worth noting. =D

Comment: Thanks Devin, yes it was just an example. I know layout is key too ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Design is one of those things that is very difficult to teach. Only a small percentage of it can be taught. The rest must be learned through experience and practice. If you have an inclination toward art / expression, your learning curve will be much shorter. Here are some things to get you started:

Color Theory:

http://www.tigercolor.com/color-lab/color-theory/color-theory-intro.htm

http://www.colormatters.com/colortheory.html

Design Basics:

http://desktoppub.about.com/cs/graphicdesign/a/designbasics.htm

http://www.online.tusc.k12.al.us/tutorials/grdesign/grdesign.htm

Software:

http://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator/

http://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop/compare/

Software Tutorials:

http://www.adobe.com/designcenter/video_workshop/

Answer (score 1):

If you're really only interested in making your app look nicer, going with one of the built-in themes from the latest Silverlight Toolkit is probably a smart choice.

Check out the links below.

[Toolkit -Themes](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Silverlight%20Toolkit%20Overview%20Part%203)

[Jesse Liberty Blog - Themes](http://jesseliberty.com/2008/10/28/toolkit-release-themes/)

EDIT:
I'm not much of a designer myself, but I know if I wanted some insight on the subject, I would start by going to the Silverlight Showcase page and seeing some of the things that can be done, and drawing inspiration from these apps.

[Silverlight Showcase](http://silverlight.net/Showcase/)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I'm familiar with the toolkit themes but I'd like to make my own look and feel.

Comment: Also most of the new themes are pretty lacklustre, Dave's Glossy Controls immediately blew them all out of the water in terms of quality. Pity he didn't do any of the toolkit controls.

Answer (score 1):

Visit the [Cooper](http://www.cooper.com/insights/books/) site.  The books listed there are well worth a read.  "About Face" in particular belongs in the library of anyone required to do UI work.

Comment: I'll pick up that book, thanks.